# Can IIS Smooth Streaming be used as a CDN server?

Tags: iis-7, video-streaming, cdn

I have a requirement of streaming millions of videos on demand. I read that CDN are the best option for that. But i recently came to know about IIS Smooth Streaming. Can anybody tell me, will IIS Smooth Streaming perform same as a CDN in streaming millions of files or does it has its own limitations (and is not a good option).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS smooth streaming cannot ever come close to CDN. A CDN is a large distributed system of servers deployed in multiple data centers across the world, and the CDN takes the responsibility of sending the users the the nearest physical server when a request comes.

To stream millikns of videos on demand, CDN is your only hope !

Comment: Hi Aby, thanks for reply. Can you tell me, will IIS Smooth Streaming allow me to add videos on fly to server and stream those videos without any encoding done on it using Microsoft Expression Encoder. Because as iam reading stuff, i came to know that videos should be first encoded using Expression Encoder and then published to IIS Smooth Streaming server. And it has to be done can this process be automated.

Comment: @shakti, for any kind of streaming to be done (IIS/WMS/FMS), your video have to be encoded to the appropriate format (wmv/h.264, mp4). What I gather from your question "to be automated" is, you want to stream videos on the fly without first encoding and uploading to IIS, right ? You will *have* to encode the video, but you can encode the video on the fly while pushing it to the streaming server. You will have to use Flash media sever or windows media server, create a publishing point, and use a suitable encoder to "push" your video stream to the server while it gets encoded on the fly.

Comment: i will just brief my project requirement. Plz guide me. I will have some clients (who are distributors), who would upload their videos on server. These videos would be viewed by other clients (who are subscribers). Now when videos are uploaded by distributor on server. I want those videos to be available for streaming to my subscriber. In this case will i need to encode any kind of video while uploading. Or can i upload the file as it is on the server and the server will do the job of streaming as per the request from client(subscriber). Will CDN help me in this case.?

Comment: yes, you will have to encode those videos your customers upload, unless its already encoded. There are few softwares which can do automatic encoding of video files, if placed on a specifie directory, and once encoded, it will be placed into another directory, from where it can be streamed. Look for "Carbon Coder", which can do this kind of encoding.

Comment: If i use Amazon S3 as a CDN, will i require to do encoding there aswell. Because when i read about Amazon S3 and its implementation about pushing any file. It was not mentioned of encoding the file before it is streamed. Plz help out.

Comment: Like I said, any video needs to be encoded or transcoded. But looks like amazon elastic transcoder will do it internally for you, sothat you can upload raw videos, and amazon will do it under the hood. http://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/ This may be what you will be wanting, sothat the hurdle of encoding can be pushed to amazon.